# Bash script error / integer expression expected

Tags: bash, curl

I'm trying to call CURL to check the latency of a website and to be able to return the execution time in the $ CURL variable to monitor this response time. Here is the program :

```
CURL=`curl 'http://www.perdu.com' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,ja;q=0.6' -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.86 Safari/537.36' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' --compressed -s -o /dev/null -w  "%{time_starttransfer}"`

if [ "$CURL" -le 1 ]
then
    rm -f $PIDFILE
    echo "UP"
else
    rm -f $PIDFILE
fi
exit
```

When I try to compare the variable $ CURL, I have the following error which returned:

```
[: {0.013}: integer expression expected
```

I think there is an invisible character in my CURL variable which prevents comparing with int but I can't see it.

Execution:

```
***@***:~$ CURL=`curl 'http://www.perdu.com' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,ja;q=0.6' -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.86 Safari/537.36' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' --compressed -s -o /dev/null -w  "%{time_starttransfer}"`
****@**:~$ echo $CURL
0,185413
```

Comment: What is the content of your `CURL` variable. I'm not going to execute some random command on my system to check what it does.

Comment: Do you mean `if [ $? -ne 0 ]` ? `cur` returns `0` on success `1 - XX` on error.

Comment: Actually read and understand the error message. Your `CURL` variable contains a floating-point number, but Bash can only handle integer arithmetic. (Also, the variable contains curly braces around it, so it's not even parseable as a number.)

Comment: I have added to my question the result of the command execution. @DavidC.Rankin, not it return the time in seconds.

Comment: Tangentially, http://shellcheck.net/ points out a number of other stylistic and robustness issues with your code.

Comment: @tripleee right. How can I fix this? Thank you :)

Comment: The duplicate explains exactly how you can fix this. Use a tool which supports floating point numbers, such as `bc` or Awk, or make `curl` output an integer expression.

Comment: This will round down for you `echo "${CURL}" | awk '{print int($1)}'` so you can use that in your if statement.